# How to distinguish HTML and javascript links?

Tags: hyperlink, links

Sometimes the link is not a HTML link, but only a javascript function call. But the text in html browser looks the same. Blue-ish and underlines on hover. [The link.](http://www.google.com)

Is there a way to distinguish these two in common browsers like Firefox or Chrome? Hovering over link to see popup is cumbersome. Can I highlight them in different color or something? Is there an addon or extension? Or greasmonkey script?

Thank you

Comment: If I understand the question right, then the title and question phrase things badly because I would say that it is all HTML.  You want to distinguish between HTML hyperlinks that use JavaScript, from simple anchor hyperlinks.  (Clarifying might help get you the help you seek.)  Anyway, I doubt that Firefox or Chrome support what you're asking, but I do bet that this functionality can be added using an add-on, or maybe a JavaScript bookmarklet (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23422305/4411648)), though an add-on would probably be able to be more automatic (and, therefore, preferable)

Comment: Yes, but I want to distinguish between any HTML link (not just anchor) and link with javascript call in it. Yeah, addon would be nice.

Comment: "(not just anchor)"... well, if you know anything about HTML links, you likely know that the HTML says "`<A HREF=`" (or variations, like additional attributes, or lowercase which is optional in HTML and mandatory in XHTML).  The "`A`" stands for "anchor".  So your "(not just anchor)" comment implies another type of HTML link you're trying to refer to (maybe the "<LINK" tag, used for referencing CSS, FavIcon.ico files, and more?), but I don't think that's what you were meaning to say.

Answer (score 0):

Answer nowhere to be found, so I made a simple script for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey

https://openuserjs.org/scripts/rluks/Javascript_Link_Distinguisher_(JLD)

Feedback is appreciated